# User-based dynamic permissions with Zend_ACL

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-acl

Is it possible to assign users individual permissions based on dynamic elements in a Zend Framework application?

I have tables like so:

```
clients (id, name, contact_name, contact_number, logo, active)
modules (id, client_id, module_id, active)
permissions (id, user_id, client_id, module_id)
users (id, username, password, email, realname)
```

What I need to do is allow a specific user to access a specific module for each individual client, but I can't figure out any way to get Zend_ACL to do this. What would be the most efficient way to do so?

**Edit:** Apologies, I forgot to add a detail. I have to allow an administrator to grant and revoke permissions from users in an administration interface.

Comment: Yes, of course it is possible. Zend_Acl is very flexible. You can fetch user roles and permissions from database, xml file or really anything you'd like. You can even hardcode them but that's not very usual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this post, as I think it may have some of what you are wanting.  FYI, this is the 3rd part of the series, but more pertinent to what you are asking.

http://codeutopia.net/blog/2009/02/18/zend_acl-part-3-creating-and-storing-dynamic-acls/

Answer (score 1):

Let's open back this topic, it is good to finish it, and it is a quite a little bit difficult in the implementation.
Let's make sense on the issue that we have:
Ben: I don't know your project what is going about, but let's create a similar scenario,
We have a website for Guests, Clients, Administrators:
We need a table in our database to save the Roles Names, and for each Role it have its permissions

> ```
> Roles (idRole, nameRole)
> Permissions (We will speak about it later)
> ```

Let's say, may be later, we will need to set more Roles for our application, so we will set a page for the administrator to assign the permissions for each Role (Like Drupal and Joomla), one of the solutions is to locate all modules that you have in your application, then get the Controllers for each module, and the actions for each Controller.
and then we have to tell to Zend_Acl to set our roles from the Roles Table in the database, and the Resources are the Zend Modules->Actions for each controller.
So we will need, a Table to store all Modules, and for each module we will need the controllers and the actions

> ```
> Modules (idModule, nameModule)
> Controllers (idController, nameController, idModule_FK)
> Actions (idAction, nameAction, descriptionAction, idController_FK)
> ```

The description field will get it from the Action description example

> ```
> /**
> * @description := Action to edit Roles
> **/
> public function editAction {}
> ```

So now let's complete our database structure

> ```
> Roles (idRole, nameRole)
> Permission (idRole, allowedPermission, idAction, dateTimeAssigned)
> Modules (idModule, nameModule)
> Controllers (idController, nameController, idModule_FK)
> Actions (idAction, nameAction, descriptionAction, idController_FK)
> ```

Here is a general structure, that I could find until now, I am trying to get back all the modules/controllers/actions, when it will done, I will post it back here (the plugin class) then we will try to move all together (Contribution for others) to handle this matter with Zend_Acl Dynamic.

Next Steps: To create a Plugin in the `Library/App/Action/Helper` if it is done by someone please post back to have a general contribution about it, 
Then we will focus on saving the Data using Doctrine ORM with our Zend Project, 
3rd Step is to create a Controller that creates the Zend_Acl dynamically from the database information (Role, Permissions, Actions).

Any Advises/Ideas/Suggestions, here where should continue until being finished.

Kind regards,

Comment: I honestly can't tell if this is an answer or a question.

Answer (score 0):

The basic framework behind ACLs can be for example like this

```
$acl = new Zend_Acl();

// allow user with ID 1 access reports section for client with ID 4
$acl->allow(
  new Zend_Acl_Role('user_1'),
  new Zend_Acl_Resource('reports'),
  'client_4'
);

// allow administrator access reports module for all clients
$acl->allow(
  new Zend_Acl_Role('administrator'),
  'reports'
);
```

And so on...
It pretty much depends on you which style you prefer. Zend_Acl is very flexible and I agree that the manual could have been written with more examples and best practices, but in the end it is not that hard to figure it out on your own.

Comment: Is there a way to load that from a MySQL backend (or a model)?

Comment: As the logic for ACL is different from application to application, Zend_Acl does not directly support loading data from database. You should do it in 2 steps - a) load the data from db; b) parse the data and populate Zend_Acl. It's not a bug deal though.